# Question about bonds coupon rate vs. interest rate

Tags: bonds

I'm new to this subject, but from looking around the internet, I know bonds have a coupon rate that is predetermined. However, the actual interest rate could change due to government and/or market conditions.

My question is this. Do investors get paid the coupon rate, or the actual interest (yield?) rate?

Because if the coupon rate is paid, then theoretically isn't the risk 0% since it's always going to be a set percentage? But if investors are paid the actual interest rate, then what is the point of having a coupon rate?

As you can see I'm very confused about the subject. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a fixed-rate bond, the stated coupon is what you'll get (unless it's a discount bond that simply matures at par). As long as you hold the bond to maturity and there's no default, you'll receive all of your coupons over the bond's life, and the par value at maturity.

The coupon rate is the rate when the bond is at par. For example, a $1,000 par bond with a 5% coupon pays coupons of $50.

The current yield is the interest rate given the bond's current price. For example, if the above bond was currently trading at a premium of $1,200, the current rate would be $50 / $1,200 = 4.167%.

There's another yield, the yield to maturity (YTM). Remember that bonds mature at par value, so your true rate of return needs to include both the coupon payments and the price appreciation/depreciation. YTM also assumes your coupons are reinvested at the same rate.

You have several risks with bonds, including default risk (the risk that you don't get the promised payments), interest rate risk (the risk that interest rates rise, pushing down existing bond prices and being unable to invest at higher rates since your money is already locked up), reinvestment risk (the risk that your coupons are reinvested at lower interest rates), call risk (the risk of an issuer redeeming a callable bond early - ties in with reinvestment risk), inflation risk, and others.

Comment: the federal reserve told large banks that interest rates would never rise, so interest rate risk doesn't exist any more :) (this comment is sarcastic. In 2023, several banks collapsed because interest rate risk materialized)

Comment: I know you're joking, but I don't think the fed ever even hinted at that .. rather the opposite...